# How to concat 2 counts from difference tables in Mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT count(*) FROM users; --result is 15 
SELECT count(*) FROM tasks; --result is 270
```

I need to get this result `15,270` in one cell.

Comment: i am sorry, second page not users, for example table2

Comment: how you have two different result from the same table  and same query  ... your question is not clear